# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getMonth' of undefined

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm making a REST API in Node and I got a problem. I'm trying to validate that a user in the registration form doesn't put an invalid year, month and day (like month 13 or day 65). With validating year it works but none of month or day works, I don't know why.

Here's the code:

```
    //Variables para verificar si es mayor a 18 a;os
    var month = newUser.birthDate.getMonth() + 1;
    console.log(month);
    var year = newUser.birthDate.getFullYear();
    var day = newUser.birthDate.getDate();
    console.log(day);
    var day_actual = new Date().getDate();
    var month_actual = new Date().getMonth();
    var year_actual = new Date().getFullYear();
    var edad = year_actual - year;

    if ((year > 1930) && (year <= year_actual) && (month > 0) && (month <= 12) && (day > 0) && (day <= 31)) {
        if ((month == 2) && (day > 28)) {
            res.status(406).send({ message: "Error, febrero solo tiene 28 dias" });
        } else {
            if (year > year_actual) {
                res.status(500).send({ error: 'El año es mayor al año actual' });
            } else {
                if (month > month_actual) {
                    edad--;
                } else if ((month_actual == month) && (day > day_actual)) {
                    edad--;
                }

                if (edad >= 18) {
                    createUser(newUser, function(err, user) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        console.log(user);
                        res.status(200).send({ message: 'Se ha registrado' });
                    });
                } else {
                    res.status(500).send({ error: 'EL usuario debe tener 18 anos' })
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        res.status(406).send({ message: "Año, mes o día inválido. Por favor introduzca un año entre 1930 y el año actual, mes entre 1 y 12, día entre 1 y 31" });
    }
```

Error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getMonth' of undefined

Comment: What does `console.log(newUser.birthDate);` show if you put it in before your first line?

Comment: Is `newUser.birthDate` a Javascript Date object? If you get a date string, or a timestamp, you first have to convert it to a Date object with `var userBirthDate = new Date(newUser.birthDate)`.

Comment: If I put 13 as a month it says undefined

Comment: Yes, newUser.birthDate it's a JS Date object, within a MongoDB model

Comment: The error message indicates that newUser.birthDate is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

If you put in `month = 13`, there will probably be thrown an exception because the given format is not valid for a month. So there's already a layer that validates what input you're giving into the object (since it's a Date object).

If there's thrown an exception, it will get handled somewhere and the object normally assigned a date, will now not be assigned at all and hold `undefined`, giving you the error `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'getMonth' of undefined"`.

Your solution is to either catch any exception that is thrown upon assigning `birthDate`, or just assume that the `undefined` value for `birthDate` means invalid data was passed by the user.

Answer (score 0):

That means, on your codes somewhere moment js is parsing something which is not a valid date